# show uploaded image using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

After file upload, it gets saved in the db with its real name.ext but a different name something-cryptic.ext in the uploaded directory. I am trying to show the uploaded image,`@user.legal_docs.url` but it does not render anything. I checked my network tool bar and found that it was referencing in the right directory but the filename was incorrect, it was something-else-cryptic without extension.

original file name in db = xyz.jpg

file in uploaded dir = something-cryptic.ext

image name when issuing `@user.legal_docs.url` = something-else-cryptic

### User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
  has_attached_file :legal_docs,
                    url: '/system/:hash.:extension',
                    hash_secret: 'abc123'

  validates_attachment :legal_docs,
                       content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'] },
                       size: { in: 0..1024.kilobytes }
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :omniauthable, :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  def facebook
    identities.where(provider: 'facebook').first
  end

  def facebook_client
    @facebook_client ||= Facebook.client(access_token: facebook.accesstoken)
  end

  def twitter
    identities.where(provider: 'twitter').first
  end

  def twitter_client
    @twitter_client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV['TWITTER_APP_ID']
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV['TWITTER_APP_SECRET']
      config.access_token        = twitter.accesstoken
      config.access_token_secret = twitter.secrettoken
    end
  end
end
```

### verification_controller

```
def upload
      redirect_to client_verification_path, alert: 'No File Selected' unless params[:user]
      @user = User.find_by(id: current_user.id)
      if @user.update(photo_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Your legal document has been sent for verification. We will contact you soon'
        redirect_to client_dashboard_path
      else
        render 'index'
      end
    end

    private

    def photo_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:legal_docs) if params[:user]
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to render your file should be something like this:

```
<%= link_to "View file", @user.legal_docs.url(:original) %>
```

Comment: I had no idea that `:original` was required . I thought that it was required if I had mentioned it in the user model.